# Associating Mongo document to another through Meteor using Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

In my Meteor application, I'm struggling to associate my items with each other using their _ids. In the code below, let's say that I am trying to make one item the "child" of another, by choosing its parent from a drop-down list of all available items.

As it stands right now, I have no problems associating another item's name with an item. Unfortunately, as names are not necessarily unique, I want to associate the item with another item's _id after selecting the other item's name from a dropdown. There are two primary questions I have:

1) How do I set a default value in the select list so choosing any name results in the "change" event?

2) How do I get the "t" parameter to reference the parent item's template rather than the current template so I can grab its data?

**The code as it sits now:**

Mongo Object Schema:

```
{"items":[{
  itemText: ,
  createdAt: ,
  createdBy: ,
  checked: ,
  itemTags: [],
]};
```

HTML for the individual item - items-list.html uses {{#each}} to render all items:

```
<template name="item">
  <form class="form-inline assign-parent">
    <select class="form-control" name="text">
      {{#each parentItems}}
      {{> parentItem}} // This does return itself but I can fix that :)
      {{/each}}
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>

<template name="parentItem">
  <option>{{itemText}}</option>
</template>
```

JS for the individual item - items-list.js finds all items:

```
Template.item.helpers({
  parentItems: function() {
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    return Items.find({checked: false});
  }
});

Template.item.events({
  'change .assign-parent': function(event, t) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var selectedParentId = t.data._id;

    Items.update(this._id, {$set: {itemParentId: selectedParentId}});

    return false;
  },
});
```

Comment: These are actually two completely seperate questions. Please stick to one question per question :-). Also your title is not very good, because actually in the end you say, you know how to do what you ask in your title, but you are struggling with other details. I will answer non the less. But please try to be clearer on what you need and stick to one question per question.

Answer (score 0):

1) How to set a default value

Here it depends on what you actually want, you can easily add a label like "Pick one..." like the this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="text">
  <option disabled selected>Pick one</option>
  {{#each parentItems}}
    {{> parentItem}}
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

If you want to show the current value in the dropdown, you have to use a custom helper (see [Meteor select element setting selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701935/meteor-select-element-setting-selected-value))

2) Getting the right values

Actually you need both values, so getting Template.parentItem context is actually not really helpful. Keep it this way but the selected value from the form.

So give each option its id

```
<template name="parentItem">
  <option id="{{_id}}">{{itemText}}</option>
</template>
```

And handle it accordingly in the events

```
Template.item.events({
  'change .assign-parent': function(event) {
    var selectedParentId = $(event.target).find(":selected").attr("id");
    Items.update(this._id, {$set: {itemParentId: selectedParentId}});
  },
});
```